# Migrando web, fallo en el registro de formulario php + mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

---

### Fallo en registro, campos not be null.

---

Si los hago null ingresa null, no los valores pasados por el formulario.

**Página del formulario**
El formulario tiene unas variable con valores por defecto, no se el proposito, se ve así.

```
//variables valores por defecto
$name = "";
$nameValue = "";

$username = "";
$usernameValue = "";
//etc etc...
```

despues de esto se validan los datos enviados

```
    //Validacion de datos enviados
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(!validateName($_POST['name']))
    $name = "error";

    if(!validateUsername($_POST['username']))
    $username = "error";
    // etc etc...
```

despues guarda los valores y se escapan caracteres especiales y se comprueba si todo fue bien, omito ese código

```
//Guardamos valores para que no tenga que reescribirlos
$nameValue = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['name'])));
$usernameValue = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['username'])));
$emailValue = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link,$_POST['email']);
$passwordValue = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link,$_POST['password2']);
```

luego se prepara el form con todos los campos, values etc, se manda por post etc... un trozo, no quiero aburrir pero que no falte.

```
<form id="form1" action="registro.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="name">Nombre <?php if ($name == "error"): echo "<span style=color:red>"; else: echo "<span style=color:green>"; endif; ?>A-z, mínimo 3 caracteres, sin tildes ni espacios.</span></label>
<span id="sprytextfield1">
<input tabindex="1" name="name" id="name" type="text" class="text <?php echo $name ?>" value="<?php echo $nameValue ?>" />
<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Se necesita un valor.</span></span>
```

en un archivo con las funciones se preparan las sentencias, huelga poner la conexión pero la pongo

```
    <?php if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
//Configuración.
      $hostname_db = "localhost";
      $username_db = "root";
      $password_db = "";
      $database_db = "cuerodb";

//INICIAMOS CONEXIÓN.
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $link = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","","cuerodb");
    $link->set_charset("utf8");
  }catch(Exception $e) {
  error_log($e->getMessage());
  exit('Error en el proceso');
    }
}
?>
```

y a continuación las sentencias preparadas, empiezo con un require_once a pesar que lo tengo arriba en el top de la página, no se, si lo quito no funciona...

```
require_once('../Connections/sbrweb.php');      
    //Configuración.
    $hostname_db = "localhost";
    $database_db = "cuerodb";
    $username_db = "root";
    $password_db = "";

    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db); 
    $link-> set_charset("utf8");
    mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);

// Comprobar conexión

if($link->connect_error){
    die("La conexión ha fallado, error número " . $link->connect_errno . ": " . $link->connect_error);
} 

        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO users_temp (nombre, usersTemp, password, email, txt_Activ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $nombre, $usersTemp, $password, $email, $txtActiv);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo $link->info;
        // EJECUTANDO SENTENCIA PREPARADA 
if ($stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT nombre, usersTemp, password, email, txt_Activ FROM users_temp")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    // Vinculamos variables a columnas
    $stmt->bind_result($nombre, $usersTemp, $password, $email, $txt_Activ);
    // Obtenemos los valores
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s %s %s %s \n", $nombre, $usersTemp, $password, $email, $txt_Activ);
    }
    // Cerramos la sentencia preparada
    $stmt->close();
}
}
```

Bien he querido dar toda la información posible, resumen rápido.
Ya no hay error de la consulta preparada, al cambiar los campos de la base de datos a nulo Sí, predeterminado NULL inserta, pero inserta esto... 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ayuda, yo no se y estoy desesperado, google es un caos para el que no sabe.

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta. ¿Cuál es el error en sí? ¿En qué parte del código?

Comment: @A.Cedano hola. No se realiza el registro en la D.B ese es el problema principal. Por qué ya averigué, (falta solucionarlo), al parecer esta mal el prepare, no sé por qué. Voy a intentar editar mi pregunta.

Comment: Ok. Tómalo con calma, explica bien el problema, con sencillez y te ayudaremos. Si das una serie de explicaciones con poca claridad es imposible que entendamos el problema y podamos ayudarte. No estamos en tu cabeza, ni en tu lógica, ni en tu pantalla, por lo que tienes que exponer el problema de forma que se entienda y diciendo *aquí está el problema*. Si nos sueltas todo el código para analizarlo tratando de analizar la lógica y luego encontrar el problema pones las cosas más difícil. Y, aprende cómo se usa el sitio. Cualquier aclaración puedes [edit] la pregunta y modificarla o añadir algo.

Comment: Gracias por vuestra paciencia, todo esto es nuevo para mi, intentaré acomodarme lo antes posible.

Comment: He aprendido y editado no sin esfuerzo la pregunta que realice ayer, espero que podais ayudarme, saludos.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. ¿puedo eliminar esta pregunta y formular otra? he averiguado mas cosas. Necesito avanzar, paso muchas horas leyendo y haciendo pruebas y sigo sin arreglar la inserción, se qué es, no como solucionarlo. Espero pacientemente pero no quiero estar estático, disculpadme.

Comment: Puedes [edit] esta misma pregunta para añadir las aclaraciones necesarias. Lo que sí te recomiendo es que borres la no-respuesta que has escrito tú mismo. Actualmente la pregunta aparece como resuelta porque has activado el check verde en esa no-respuesta que no resuelve el problema en realidad. Si lo dejas así los usuarios creerán que está resuelto, cuando no lo está.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por los consejos. En los comentarios de abajo hay una explicación a por qué está contestada. Te resumo, conteste yo donde no debía (novato) y meti mal el email, se genero un usuario y ya pedi al staff que se elimine al usuario "error" y la pregunta (que edité ayer pero hoy vuelve a salir). El combinar cuentas no resulta por que al email error no llegara, o al menos no se esos datos de acceso a esa cuenta si existe. Saludos

Comment: Up, ayuda por favor. Si no borro y cierro. No es lo mio.

Comment: B días, hola. Solucionado en parte. Sabía que habia una dependencia que hacia mal, las variables en bind_param las metia mal ya que van con un _ al final, no sé por qué, $nombre_, $email_ etc... ¿Ahora que hago cierro, le doy a resuelto, no tengo ni idea?